# REST API for associating Xray configuration/coverage with jira project programmatically

Tags: jira, atlassian-sourcetree, jira-rest-api, jira-xray

I want to automate the manual process of associating a jira project with xray so that projects can leverage the features of xray. 
I have explored various jira and xray api's available at https://confluence.xpand-it.com/display/public/XRAY/REST+API but could not find any API which can help in doing so.

Automating this with selenium or htmlunit is one option but it will be time consuming if there are more projects.

Is there any workaround/trick to automate this or if there's any undocumented api which can help in associating jira projects to xray plugin. Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a way to do this programmatically. No need of using ScriptRunner's custom REST API capabilities as documented [here](https://confluence.xpand-it.com/display/XRAY360/Extending+and+integrating+with+Xray+using+ScriptRunner#ExtendingandintegratingwithXrayusingScriptRunner-Requirementprojects)

Configure the headers as below,

```
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
X-Atlassian-Token:no-check
```

Access the below **GET** call with the required query parameters,

```
https://{YOUR_JIRA_HOME_URL}/XrayRequirementProjectsConfiguration.jspa?makeCompatible={PROJECT_KEY}
```

Specify the project key of the project for which you would like to enable the XRAY coverage.